# Create a Spring Insight template

Tags: tcserver, spring-insight

I am just listing here the basic steps to create a Spring Insight web application using Spring tcServer developer edition. I haven't found much doco regarding this, so it could help some people.

1 - Download Spring Tool Suite here
[Download STS](http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts)

Extract the archive somewhere on your machine, open a terminal and go to **~/tc-server-developer-[VERSION]/**

2 - Run the following commands

`./tcruntime-instance.sh create -t insight myInstance`

This one creates a new tcServer instance based on the template **insight**. (full list of templates can be found in **~/tc-server-developer-[VERSION]/templates/**)

Go to **~/tc-server-developer-[VERSION]/myInstance/bin/** and run the following

`./tcruntime-ctl.sh start`

This will start your tcServer instance based on the Spring Insight template. Check it is working by pointing your favourite browser to the URL `http://localhost:8080/insight`. That should display the Spring Insight index page.

Now you just have to drop your web app in the **~/tc-server-developer-[VERSION]/myInstance/webapps/** folder and Bob's your uncle !

Comment: Please present this in Question/Answer format, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also wanted to mention how to set this up from the IDE without having to do any command line work
Assuming you have a spring mvc project open already in STS.  This took a while to find so thank you for posting.

- Add a new server from the servers window. Select the VFabric tcServer
- Create new instance
- When you get to the part where it asks you to select a template pick the insight template.
- Add you app to the server you just created
- Start the server
- You will be prompted if youwant to activate insight, click yes.
- Navigate to localhost:8080/insight   or whatever port it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details here: http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.6/devedition/install.html&path=2_3_1_0